# implementing HTTP2 on nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl, http2

I'm trying to implement an HTTP2 server on my nodejs project but somehow i'm getting this error:

> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

In my index file i have:

```
https.createServer({key: ssl_config.key, cert: ssl_config.cert}, app.callback()).listen(ssl_config.port.https)

http2.createServer({key: ssl_config.key, cert: ssl_config.cert}, app.callback()).listen(ssl_config.port.http2)
```

The `https` module works fine but the `http2` isn't working